Trimming a video using FFmpeg leads to black screen
I try to figure out how to use FFmpeg to trim videos. I have created a 30 second .mov screen capture using Apple's QuickTime player, and then tried to trim it using three different ways:

Using -copyts, without re-encoding
ffmpeg -copyts -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -to 00:00:15 -map 0 -c copy output.mov


Using -copyts, with re-encoding
ffmpeg -copyts -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -to 00:00:15 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mov


Using -trim (with re-encoding, which is the only option):
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf trim=10:15 output.mov



No matter which approach I tried, the output video is always 15 seconds long and the first 10 seconds of that is just a black screen, whereas what I expected is a 5-second video and without the black screen.
All the three solutions are from here: https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg (answers by @slhck and @malat), and are very high-voted, so I expect they should work without issues, but they don't. Why is that? Is there a problem with the commands, or with the video?
The video is uploaded here: https://github.com/jsx97/test/blob/main/input.mov

from doc: -copyts → Do not process input timestamps, but keep their values without trying to sanitize them. In particular, do not remove the initial start time offset value. If use trim, add setpts -vf trim=10:15,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS

@БаярГончикжапов That is, if using -copyts, this is a natural behavior? Then this is somewhat strange that "how to trim a video using FFmpeg" solutions , which are often based on -copyts, don't mention this "black screen" issue.

maybe, it can be used to syncronize videos from surveillance cameras

@БаярГончикжапов And when you need to trim a video, which approach you use yourself, -trim or something else?

mostly, ffmpeg -ss 5 -to 15 -i in out
